# Rails 6 Capistrano Deployment to production does not serve css and js files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, capistrano, capistrano3

I have a Rails 6 app using webpacker for assets. I am deploying the app using `capistrano`.

The app words well locally and serves my css and js files but on production CSS and JS files are not applied

Here are my config files.

`config/deploy.rb`

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.16.0"
require 'capistrano-db-tasks'

set :application, "my_app"
set :repo_url, "git@gitlab.com:myname/myapp.git"

set :use_sudo, false

set :rvm_map_bins, %w{gem rake ruby rails bundle puma pumactl sidekiq sidekiqctl}

# if you want to remove the local dump file after loading
set :db_local_clean, false

# Default branch is :master
ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

set :use_sudo, false
set :bundle_binsstubs, nil

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :app_path, "#{deploy_to}/current"

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, false

# Default value for :linked_files is []
append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/application.yml', 'config/sidekiq.yml'

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Capistrano DB Tasks
# if you want to remove the local dump file after loading
# set :db_local_clean, true

# if you want to remove the dump file from the server after downloading
# set :db_remote_clean, true

# if you are highly paranoid and want to prevent any push operation to the server
set :disallow_pushing, false

# If you want to import assets, you can change default asset dir (default = system)
# This directory must be in your shared directory on the server
set :assets_dir, %w(public/uploads)
set :local_assets_dir, %w(public/uploads)

### Puma Configuration ###
set :nginx_use_ssl, true
set :puma_workers, 2

# Only attempt migration if db/migrate changed
set :conditionally_migrate, true
after 'deploy:updated', 'assets:precompile'

namespace :rake do
  desc 'Runs rake tasks on remote server'
  task :fix_order_count => [:set_rails_env] do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, "customer:fix_order_count"
        end
      end
  end
end
```

`lib/capistrano/tasks/precompile.rake`

```
# lib/capistrano/tasks/precompile.rake
namespace :assets do
  desc 'Precompile assets locally and then rsync to web servers'
  task :precompile do
    run_locally do
      with rails_env: stage_of_env do
        execute :bundle, 'exec rake assets:precompile'
      end
    end

    on roles(:web), in: :parallel do |server|
      run_locally do
        execute :rsync,
          "-a --delete ./public/packs/ #{fetch(:user)}@#{server.hostname}:#{shared_path}/public/packs/"
        execute :rsync,
          "-a --delete ./public/assets/ #{fetch(:user)}@#{server.hostname}:#{shared_path}/public/assets/"
      end
    end

    run_locally do
      execute :rm, '-rf public/assets'
      execute :rm, '-rf public/packs'
    end
  end
end
```

`config/environments/production.rb`

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

Rails.application.configure do
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress CSS using a preprocessor.
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Fingerprint assets digest
  # config.assets.digest = true

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]


  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log disallowed deprecations.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation = :log

  # Tell Active Support which deprecation messages to disallow.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation_warnings = []

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

end
```

Comment: What errors did you get when you deployed to production? It's probably a precompiling issue on production. Did you try to precompile for production environment in your local machine to see what kind of errors you get on your terminal?

Comment: Totally no error. [A gist link to my deployment log](https://gist.github.com/coremuscle254/550191e07ea01e1ed648ffe16c8ea75c)

I precompile on my local with no errors. After deployment I can even view my images using <%= image_pack_tag 'specific_image' %> but css and js is not showing on the rendered HTML

Comment: I am actually precompiling on local machine and copying that over to the server using the rake task `lib/capistrano/tasks/precompile.rake`

Comment: In your terminal locally did you try to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` see if you get any errors. Or go though all your css, in vs code you can open your scss files and open vs code integrated terminal and click on problems. Most likely you missed something.

Comment: If I missed something would this not throw errors on dev mode too? I have also run the task and the precompile on production ENV runs smoothly